# SQL Server : I can not restore a .bak file on query marks an error and on GUI do not show me nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup, restore

I want to restore a database from a SQL Server on linux red hat to my SQL Server on windows. I have the same version that linux uses, and the same version of SQL Server Management Studio, but the `.bak` file does not work.

I import the file on GUI, I can find the file and the import to gui, but not show me the data on the file, but the file is not empty and on the query marks an error that the file is corrupted, but SQL Server on linux can restore the `.bak` file perfectly. I get the file from FTP.

These are the errors that are shown in the console:

> Msg 3287, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The file ID 1 on device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\dbPruebaSql-Full.bak' is incorrectly formed and can not be read.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Perhaps the file is corrupting over FTP?

Comment: how can solution this? i can access only for ftp to server linux